# How to retrieve projects from expired TFS server

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs, sql-server-2012, trial

I was testing the msbuild and made a sqlproject and a deploy process template which I have to show working in order to actually buy tfs, but my TFS trial licence expired and since I work every time on a vm I've lost all local data.

How can I retrieve my project?

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft allows you to obtain new trial ID's and extend your time.

[Extending Trials of TFS 2010,TFS 2012 and beyond](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bharry/archive/2010/05/07/extending-trials-of-tfs-2010.aspx)

Also if you have an MSDN subscription you can find a license key there.  That and it's only around $500 to buy a license.